# How to resize drawable in a TextInputEdit

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable, android-textinputedittext

I have a `TextInputEditText` field to write numbers down. I want to add a drawable symbol to the end of my `InputText` which already worked.

The problem is, that my text and the drawable are not the same size...So I want to resize the drawable to the same size as my text. How could I do this?

The XML code is here:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="amount"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/amount_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_percent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is an example how it looks right now:

[image]

Comment: Use a SVG as your drawable

Comment: the ic_percent was a svg, I could solve it with the code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, so I would like to share it with you:

```
val drawable1: Drawable=inputField.compoundDrawablesRelative[position] //get Drawable from Input
drawable1.setBounds(0,0,15.toPx(),15.toPx()) // set size
inputField.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,symbol1,null) // set position of drawable
```

Comment: you also can get the drawable with: val img: Drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.something) (.. if you haven't modified it through xml)